# Array item is a closure object, can I get its return value as the same array item?

Tags: php, arrays, closures

I have this array:

```
$people = array( 
   'kids' => 100, 
   'adults' => function() {
       return 1000
   }
);
```

If I do `print_r($people)` I get:

`Array ([kids] => 100, [adults] => Closure Object() )`

How do I get - **at that same array position** - the return value of the closure object instead of the Closure Object itself?

Is this possible in PHP ?

Comment: `$people['adults']()`? if you want the actual value in the array, though, why have a closure in the first place?

Comment: because the value has to be computed and I wanted to have the function calculating it in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myFunction = function() { return 1000; };
$people = array( 'kids' => 100, 'adults' => $myFunction());
```

If you try to do it inline like this:

```
$people = array( 'kids' => 100, 'adults' => function() { return 1000; }());
```

You will get a parse error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

If you must do it on one line, you can use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$people = array( 
    'kids' => 100, 
    'adults' => call_user_func(function(){ return 1000; })
);
```

Comment: I thought of that, but if I use `call_user_func` I get: *Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context*

Comment: I know why I get that error but still can fix it: it's because the closure is calling `$this->input->post('account')` (I am using Code Igniter) ...

Comment: Anyway, without taking into consideration the complications of my specific use case, your answer is correct, so marking it as such. Thanks!